# Unable to set/use session variables in ruby on rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Can somebody tell me the right way to set/use session variables in a ruby on rails application from scratch. I am not able to set/use a session variable in my controller between two pages. I am using CookieStore session type. This is the syntax being used to set and get session variables:

```
session[:test] = "testing"

@test_str = session[:test]
```

Let me know in case I am missing on something.

This is how my controller looks like:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /merchant_test  
  def merchant_test
    session[:test] = "testing"
    render :layout => false 
  end

  # POST /post_to_mobikwik
  def post_to_mobikwik
    zr = Mobikwik::Request.new(params) 
    @mobikwik_data = zr.all_params
    @test_str = session[:test]
    render :layout => false    
  end

  # POST /z_response
  def z_response
    zr = Mobikwik::Response.new(request.raw_post)  
    @checksum_check = zr.valid?
    @mobikwik_post = zr.all_params
    @statuscode = @mobikwik_post['statuscode']
    @statusmessage = @mobikwik_post['statusmessage']
    if @statuscode == "0"
       @verified = zr.verified?
    else
       @verified = false
    end
    render :layout => false
  end
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, what happens when you do that. What's the surrounding code. Give us a full example that doesn't work. Have you checked the [documentation for session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)?

Comment: Hi Matt, I get a nil value when I try to get back the value from the session.

Comment: Added the controller as well.

Comment: do you set it in the `merchant_test` method before using it elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. I am setting it in the merchant_test method and then using it in the post_to_mobikwik method. Then printing the value of @test_str in the html(view) file.

Comment: How do you call  post actions? ajax?

Comment: No, post actions are called by appropriate post form submission to the controller.

Comment: When I am using cookies[:test] then its working alright.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have checked the documentation and I am working according to that only. Please advice if something else needs to be done except this.

Comment: You can inspect the cookie using your browser, it should contain your `test` entry. If it does not, your cookie could contain too much information (limited to 4K). One other reason why it could fail is that your session is reset, somehow. The information will be in the cookie, but not in the session (since it is cleared). Look for the `reset_session` command somewhere in a `before_action/filter` (e.g. it is generally done after log in to disable session fixation).

Comment: In your #post_to_mobikwik method, what does `Rails.logger.debug(session)` output?

Comment: Hi hjing, Output of Rails.logger.debug(session) is {} i.e. its not printing anything.

Comment: Hi nathanvda, I have checked in my application and there is no statement like reset_session anywhere. Can you suggest something else. Should I post the whole application here ?

Comment: which gem you have used for session store?

Comment: Hi Малъ Скрылевъ, for session store management I have not configured any gem. Is this any specific file to which you are referring ? And is it necessary to use a gem ? If yes then how should I use it.

Comment: The error is not in the code you posted here.  It's most likely in the configuration somewhere or other non-local effects.  @nathanvda's suggestion is best: first inspect the cookie in your browser, it will be encrypted, but you can at least see if it's being set.  This is the first step in bisecting the problem—determine whether it's the setting or the getting that's the problem. ... another random thought: if the Secure flag is set for the cookie and you are mixing http/https requests.

Comment: Hi gtd, When the controller is in the first method the cookie is set and also the session can be seen in the browser, but as soon as the controller enters in the second method the session is nil and nothing can be seen in cookie as well.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as well, but it is across different controller, there is this error on the log `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

Answer (score 1):

Your session cookie settings might be wrong. You should inspect the headers of the response and see what the Set-Cookie header looks like.

It might have a wrong domain or perhaps your cookie is https only and you're on http.

The configuration is usually done in some place like config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
Myapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  :key =>           '_appname_session_id',
  :path =>          '/',
  :domain =>        nil,   # accepted domain, for example '.example.com'  
  :expire_after =>  nil,   # the session will be expired in X seconds unless active
  :secure =>        false, # if true, cookie is valid only on https
  :httponly =>      true   # if true, javascript can't access the cookie
}
```

Comment: Hi kimmmo, thanks for your response. I tried implementing what you sugeested but it also doen't seems to work for me. Still unable to get the session parameter stored in one controller function in same controller's another function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app-name_session'
```

Comment: This is what I have in my session_store.rb file
    
    MobikwikDemo::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_mobikwik-demo_session'

Comment: Your app is `mobikwik-demo` or `mobikwik_demo`?

Comment: mobikwik-demo is my app. Though the name of my app is MobikwikDemo. Will that make a change ?

Comment: I have code like you, but app name like- app_name with underscore, not dash. And I think this is the only change...

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, in rails we create a method
in ApplicationController, called `current_user`
In [**this**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1) free RailsCast, you see exactly are you need:

Comment: I am not using active_record_store. I am using cookie_store session managment. As far as I understand in that there is no need to create any method. We should be able to directly add parameter to session arrary and again should be able to fetch the same from it. But its not happening in my application.