# Not able to access rails session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to store a specific query in session and want to access it when the call made the same method again.

In the beginning of the method I have this:

```
reports_query = session[:reports_query]
puts reports_query
```

Just before the end of the method, I have:

```
session[:reports_query] = query
```

Nothing gets printed so far. I've also tried `cookies` instead of `session`. Doesn't work. I have checked for cookie in browser. I see an auto generated string.

I have made no change in configuration. Everything is generated by `rails`.

Any help would be appreciative.

**Update**

I think, I found the reason. Everytime, I refresh the page, I get a new cookie. Is this the reason? If so, how can I have persistent cookie?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23789683/525478

Comment: @BradWerth I tried that. didn't help

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet to do that.  Anyways, I tested this locally on a Rails 4 app with the default session configuration and I also see the cookie value change on each page reload.  I am able to access session data across controllers just fine so I don't think that's your problem.

Comment: although, I understand what you are saying, I am only trying to access session in same method of a controller every time. I dono why I am not able to get the values that I have assigned.